How do I do the p-adjustement in statistical tests?
context: a study about which type of bread and/or filling attracts ants the most
I have a table with 3 columns  : the number of ants attracted, type of bread, type of filling. The question is : do tests to find whether there is a difference in the number of ants.
So first I did some pre-tests to check for the normality then the variance equality. Then one-way ANOVA to check for general difference and the filling group had significant difference and to see where exaclty, I did pairwise t-tests.
So the question is : is that enough ? If yes how do I do the p-adjustment ?
bonus question: the tests should be for independent variables right ? because in one step I am comparing just the bread types together then just the filling types together.

I assume here you are not interested in the interaction between type of bread and type of filling, because you didn't mention that.
In this kind of setting it's customary to put both predictors (type of bread and type of filling) into the same model, either to ANOVA or regression, and then using post-hoc comparison tests to look at the differences between different bread types and differences between different filling types, applying a p-value adjustment (typically Tukey's) in the post-hoc comparisons.
How you do that exactly depends on the software you are using. In R, emmeans package is very good for this. In SPSS, you'd have to use ANOVA and choose the post-hoc p-value adjustment from the ANOVA post-hoc menu.
An additional issue is that your dependent variable seems to be a count variable, in which case a regular linear model may not be the best. See, for instance, here.
